# AngularJS - Problems with ng-click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, angularjs

Following Angular Code does not work in SharePoint 2013 - On my local Machine it runs perfectly:

```
<div ng-init="value = 'off'">
<button ng-click="value = { 'on': 'off', 'off':'on'}[value]">On/Off</button>    
{{ value }}
<h1 ng-show="value == 'on'" >Foobar1</h1>
<h1 ng-show="value == 'off'" >Foobar2</h1>
```

When I click on the Button in SharePoint it shows me shortly 'foobar1', but after a second it change automatically back to 'foobar2'.

Can anybody help me on that ?

Comment: Most likely because SharePoint captures your click event in an element higher in the DOM. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, toggles are much easier with Booleans

```
<div ng-init="value = true" ng-click="value = !value">On/Off</div>    
<h1 ng-show="value" >Foobar1</h1>
<h1 ng-show="!value" >Foobar2</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Input Danny.

Found the problem - There is probably a click event on the button from SharePoint self. When you change the button to a div or span etc. then it works also in SharePoint - Here is my Code, which is working:

```
<div ng-init="value = 'off'">
<div ng-click="value = { 'on': 'off', 'off':'on'}[value]">On/Off</div>    
{{ value }}
<h1 ng-show="value == 'on'" >Foobar1</h1>
<h1 ng-show="value == 'off'" >Foobar2</h1>
```

Comment: Change the button to input type="button"

Comment: Change your ng-click to execute a function and use ``event.PreventDefault`` to stop the event bubble... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Comment: There is no event on the button you add yourself, the button click will be sent to all its parent elements, so you have to cancel that bubbling

Comment: you mean in this way: "<button ng-click="value = { 'on': 'off', 'off':'on'}[value]; event.PreventDefault;">On/Off</button>  ", right ?